# What's the official name of Typescript feature where you declare the field in the constructor itself?

Tags: typescript

I just found out that instead of doing this:

```
class Example {
    private readonly a: number;

    constructor (a: number) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

You can do this:

```
class Example {
    constructor (private readonly a: number) { }
}
```

What's an official name of this feature? (I want to be able to google more information about it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called *parameter properties*. See the docs for more info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties